# Hiding a clear button from date picker on print in firefox

Tags: html, css, datepicker

I have an input type date on a web form. When a user prints the form, the clear button (the gray circle w/ an "x" in it) prints next to the date. Obviously this isn't ideal. I have played around w/ a few moz kits but I cant make that clear button invisible on print, no matter what I have tried thus far. Also, the form is being used exclusively in Firefox. Any advice on making this work would be greatly appreciated!

I have tried using this in a css document under @media print {}

```
input[type=date]::-ms-clear {
 display: none;
 }
```

I have tried the same thing with:

```
::-webkit-search-cancel-button
```

neither has any effect.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to remove the clear button in FireFox. The ::ms-clear feature is only for Microsoft browsers, as described in the MDN documentation.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3A-ms-clear

You need to design your own date picker from scratch or use one from a library.